# error: Equations for ‘det’ have different numbers of arguments

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to calculate the determinant and I have the `det` function defined as below:

```
det :: (Double,Double) -> (Double,Double) -> Double
det _ = 0.0
det [] = error "its Empty!"
det [x] = error "contains only one point!"
det (x1, y1) (x2, y2) = (x1*y2 + x2*y1)
```

i get the following error

```
Equations for ‘det’ have different numbers of arguments
      PolygonArea.hs:11:1-11
      PolygonArea.hs:14:1-39
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the type `(Double, Double)` is always a pair of two `Double`s, never an empty or a singleton list. Second, like the error message says, your cases for `det` need to have the same number of arguments, but one are given for the first three, and two for the fourth.

Fixing all these, you get

```
det :: (Double, Double) -> (Double, Double) -> Double 
det (x1, y1) (x2, y2) = (x1 * y2 + x2 * y1)
```

Comment: ok i see what you are saying, but then how do you check if list is empty, or it contains only one point?

Comment: There is no list at all! You've defined your function so that it can only ever receive exactly two pairs of numbers.